# Failed Configuration - Null point Exception

Tags: automated-tests, testng

I am new for programming and testing. Just page object and a test case, tried to execute it. Test failed and got null point exception. If some one could help with this, that will be great.

I have googled about this, found a similar error but answer did not helped me

This is my first test case for login page:

```
package com.ProjectName.TestCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.ProjectName.PageObject.LoginPage;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class TC_LoginTest_001 extends BassClass{

    @Test
    public void loginTest()
    {
        driver.get(baseURL);

        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
        lp.setUserName(username);
        lp.setPassword(password);
        lp.clickSubmit();

        if(driver.getTitle().equals("Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage"))
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
            //logger.info("Login test passed");
        }
        else
        {
            //captureScreen(driver,"loginTest");
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
            //logger.info("Login test failed");
        }
    }


}
```

Base class to include common things:

```
package com.ProjectName.TestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class BassClass {

    public String baseURL = "http://demo.guru99.com/V4/index.php";
    public String username = "mngr201172";
    public String password = "tysemUz";
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup()
    {
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Error:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ProjectName.TestCases.BassClass.tearDown(BassClass.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:214)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

FAILED: loginTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ProjectName.TestCases.TC_LoginTest_001.loginTest(TC_LoginTest_001.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================




Expecting Automation of Login page
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to instantiate the [ChromeDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html) like:

```
driver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver();
```

since the `driver` is null you're getting an [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) on attempt to call its functions.

Check out [Design Patterns - Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) article which includes even a [sample project](https://github.com/seetest-io/eribank-pom) you can use as the basis for your experiments.

Comment: Thanks for the replu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now the browser is instantiated but came up with new error. I think it's browser compatibility. Could you please help me with this.Thanks